# How to get checkbox to display checked/unchecked status in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Currently, I have this table with a checkbox at every row in AngularJS;

```
<table class="table table-hover data-table sort display">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location</th>   
    <th>Checkbox Alert</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredList | orderBy:columnToOrder:reverse">  
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.location}}</td>  
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected" ng-change="display(selected, item)"></td>  
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have a boolean variable `{{item.checkbox_status}}` which reflects whether the checkbox should be checked or unchecked. How should I place this variable into the table html code above to get the checkbox to reflect the checking status? Or do I need to work on the controller instead?

Comment: Still wondering why I got a -ve point? Stupid, trivial question? Not sure since there are so many better programmers on StackOverflow. What is easy for you is hard for me. Please be patient.

Comment: Completely agree with your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-model is your answer.

i.e:

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="item.checkbox_status" ng-click="alert_display()" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" />
```

Reference:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Hope I helped.

Comment: Should be more proper if wanted to use   <input type="checkbox" ng-click="select(item)" ng-model="item.selected" ng-checked="item.selected">

Answer (score 1):

just adding ng-model="item.checkbox_status" to the input should do the trick

Comment: Correct answer but I can only mark one of them as the correct answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, this should be enough :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checkbox_status" ng-change="display(selected, item)">
```

Comment: Correct answer but I can only mark one of them as the correct answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
use ng-checked for showing checked and unchecked status..
$scope.selectedThings=["a", "b", "c"];
$scope.availableThings=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
<label class="col-md-6 checkbox" ng-repeat="data in availableThings">
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data && (availableThings.indexOf(data) !== -1)" />{{data}}
</label>
```